# What is the optimal trophy level for farming at a level 8 town hall?

Tags: clash-of-clans

What is the optimal trophy level range for farming at a level 8 town hall? I noticed that it becomes more and more difficult to farm resources as I level up my town hall.

Comment: Just want to mention that this is highly subjective and can change at any time. Subjective because I have clanmates at a variety of trophy levels and all can farm a lot, and I *really* mean a lot, and if there really is an optimal range, I would say that this changes as the big loot of today will have a different trophy count after being raided; apply that to the millions of villages worldwide and you can see that it's impossible for it to remain at the same trophy level.

Answer (score 2):

It is SUPER easy to make a lot of Gold/Elixir  and a modest amount of Dark  ( you won't be rolling in it, but it will build up slowly )

Trophy Range, Stay between 1900 -> 2100.  This is Crystal III, with 35k bonus of Gold/Elixir and 100 Dark.

Basically Town Hall Snipe your way to this trophy range ( attack bases with town halls on the side with a few archers, but have an army to back them up just in case they have hidden teslas, etc).  Once you get to 2000, you don't want to lose your Crystal III status, which happens if you go below 1900.

At this trophy range you'll find a good supply of side town halls, and people loaded with loot.  at th9 and th10, it is very hard to protect all the collectors, so they are often on the outside of the walls, covered by archer towers and canons.

Your strategy is to snipe town halls whenever you can, getting your 35k bonuses.  But to also find bases where the collectors are full ( learn to recognize the inside of elixir collectors full level, and the gold has a box outside that fills with coins ) and compare it to how much is in storage.  If they have 300k available and their storage looks low, and the collectors look full.  Its time to attack!  Doesn't matter if its a side town hall or not.  You don't care about getting the win, just the loot.  Time to Attack!

for Attacking we are going to go with BAM - Barbs, Archers, Minions.  Super CHEAP to train, super FAST to train.  every single barracks will be producing units very quickly.   Don't worry about spells too much, but a rage spell on hand can be useful.  Both Dark Barracks queue up minions, 2 barracks dedicated to barbs and 2 dedicated to archers.  Just keep them constantly queued up.  The ratios between troops doesn't matter too much.

Now the trick is, use as few troops as possible... for collectors on the outside,  put just enough barbs in to take them down,  for collectors over the wall, use archers,  and once they are getting used up and there is still more loot, use minions.    Once you've taken down the collectors, end your battle.  Don't try for storage unless its placed in an unprotected place.  If you only use 80 - 100 troops to do this, you'll be ready to find another battle straight away after this attack, and because this loadout trains fast, you almost never run out of troops unless you find a super juicy base that you throw all your troops at.

Your barb king ( and queen if you are at TH9) are just there as backup or to help with sniping THs.

You can EASILY make 150k to 300k doing this.  You will lose trophys, but just snipe your way back to 2000.   In an hour or two you can make several million.

This works well for people at TH8 and TH9.  You will make so much loot that most of the time your builders/lab will be busy and you will have nothing to spend it on.

This is a good time to take a break from farming and practice your war attacks,  queue up some expensive troops ( you are rich now! you don't care about making a profit on these attacks ).   Try out All Drags, or GoWipe, and experiment with all kinds of combos.  Then when you drain your Gold/Elixir a bit,  go back to your farming strategy.

Comment: Town Hall sniping isn't really possible anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You should farm at about 1200. It will mostly have Town Hall 6 to 7 which should be a solid place for farming. It has a decent amount of loot too.

Comment: I am at around 1200... Sadly loot is not decent - as compared to Army required to get the loot... I've tried goblin strategy - but but most of the bases are so strong that I m generally forced to deploy 17-18 giants with 2 healers + others... When I was at L7... being in range 900-1000 always gave me awesome loot.

Comment: I am town hall 7 and I have no problem with farming at 1400 trophies I have a hybrid base that wins most of my defences and protects my loot maybe you should try farming there.

Comment: Yeah... It was fine for me at Level TC... but became worse after I upgraded it to TC level 8. I don't seem to find an optimum Trophy Range. But I reckon I am gonna try Farming at range 1200-1300 to see if it works.

Comment: Damn, this game has become excruciatingly painful. I happened to buy some gems using real money and see that the it became super difficult to farm. Not 100% sure at the moment, but it seems game developers have AI built to lure players to buy more and more gems using real money or keep players engaged with the game for years. I tried between 1150 - 1280 trophy range. With every search I get either players with extremely good defense or players with very low loot.

Comment: I agree with Oreo, at 1200 trophies you are able to find some raids that give 400k total loot. I use 10 Giants, 8 wall breakers and the rest archers. Gets me some serious cash!

Comment: You guys should use BARCH

Comment: @GoodSp33d I prefer GO BARCH (BARCH with gobling)

Answer (score 0):

The answer will largely depend on what elixir/dark elixir you're willing to expend and what attack strategy you are planning to utilize.

Personally, I'm attacking with a Giant/Archer/Barbarian/Breakers army composition with 3 healing spells in support. I sit in the 1450-1650 trophy range. However, there are certainly other options.

BARCH is good for bases with full collectors or that are poorly designed. These can appear at any trophy range, but tend to appear more often at lower trophy levels. Sadly, I've found that these opportunities aren't as numerous or profitable at TH8 compared to TH7.

More robust attack strategies (all dragon, GOWIPE, etc) allow for higher trophy ranges and more damaging attacks, but also cost more to launch and take longer to recover from. But with most bases with ample loot now being well defended, this can still be quite profitable, especially if you're specifically looking for some resources that aren't used to rebuild your army and spells.

Trophy hunting is another tactic where the goal is to score 1 star and collect the loot bonuses. The goal is to to search for and attack as many bases as possible that are poorly designed and your attack can easily yield 50% destruction, and perhaps have a Town Hall that you can easily reach. Some drawbacks to this tactic is that you will have to climb the trophy ladder in order to score really good bonuses, which could bring you out of your sweet spot when it comes to looting the rest of the base, and expose you to higher-level players that would be more capable of obliterating your base in a raid.

Comment: Now the throphy hunting is a bit more valid, as you have star bonus each 5 stars. I usually combine a good looting with trying to get at least 1 star each attack. This gives good bonuses along with good loot in the attack itself. Combined with dropping throphies before it gets too high, but keeping it on a decent level for the amount of bonus in the league.

Comment: @awe: This answer could use some updating since the only bases now with exposed town halls are either abandoned bases, or with trapped town halls. In fact, all of the answers on this question are now out of date since the strategies they advocate for aren't really efficient anymore.