# What's best trophy range for farming TH7

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm almost maxed TH7 I have only walls left to max,I'm currently Now I need to max walls before going to TH8,I wonder what is the best trophy range to farm gold and elixir to get 150k plus resources? I looked around silver 1 and 2 but I can't find perfect trophy range. I wanted to upgraded hogs, to farm dark elixr now I'm on gold 3 and I collected 20k dark elixr for hogs. Should I drop to silver 1? Or should I stay on gold 3

Comment: You can find your answer here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/164190/what-is-the-best-trophy-level-for-farming-at-level-8-town-center - Besides, it's only that your troops are a little less powerful, you're more evenly matched and... MOAR LOOT!

Answer (score 1):

I am a fresh th7. After a few raids and league jumps, I found out that it depends upon which type of resource you are farming for.

- If you want to farm dark elixir, then 1300-1500 is the range where you get it.
- If you are looking for gold and elixir, I would recommend the 1100-1200 range of trophies.

I would also like to mention that the best way to farm DE is to play clan wars. You can take away up to 2000 in a single war with just 2 attacks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Gold league Division II and III. Anything further you are will be in town hall 8 playground and might get raided too often if your walls are not maxed. I believe Max walls for TH7 are dark purple (level 7). The light pink walls (level 6) require a single level 5 wall breaker to blast them open so if you have these mostly on your base you will be a common target for TH8s, and of coarse TH9s and TH10s.

Answer (score -1):

Drop in bronze 1, around 725 trophy is a lot of loot and easy to find around 40 searches and you find the perfect base th7 and 400k loot .

Answer (score -1):

300k of gold and elixir in silver 11 and 111. I suck so I don't reach silver 1 but I am top 20 in silver 11. Even if u see a th6 with the th unguarded pn the outside, and u get the 2%1⭐️, u will get around 50k of gold and elixir. Silver is bad for DE though

Answer (score -1):

I've been staying at Crystal as a non-max th7 for some time. The loot is amazing up here and I maxed my barb king in no time. I often max my resources and my clan castle treasury. So as long as you can 2-3 star th7s and th8s, you should be at crystal 3 or higher. I'm currently at crystal 1, trying to get to masters. Good luck!

(My highest loot raid was in crystal 3, attacking a th8. He had 600k elixir and 400k gold)

Answer (score -2):

I think that Gold III and II are good for farming anything de,  elixir and gold.  I make like 1.3 million gold and elixir per 2 hours

Answer (score -3):

I'm a middle starter th7 and I think the best trophy range for th7 is silver league I and Gold league III

Comment: Why do you think this is the best trophy range?  You've given no reasoning at all.

Comment: As @Frank said, if you believe this is the best, you should give reasoning behind it.

Answer (score -3):

Gold is the best because you get Dark in your star bonus and don't get many TH level 8 or 9s attacking you.